# Replace gaps in data frame with zero

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame `df` that contain coverage information along a `genome` for each `position`. However, positions with `coverage` 0 is not included in the original data.frame. I would like to complete the data.frame and add the gaps in column `position` and fill those with `coverage` 0. It should start at `position` 1 and and at the number in the column `length`

Original question input:

```
  > df
    genome position coverage length
1  NC_2424        3        1     30
2  NC_2424        5        1     30
3  NC_2424        6        1     30
4  NC_2424        7        1     30
5  NC_2424        8        4     30
6  NC_2424       14        4     30
7  NC_2424       15        6     30
8  NC_2424       16        2     30
9  NC_2424       20        3     30
10 NC_2424       21        1     30
```

.
Edit input with multiple genomes:

```
  > df
    genome position coverage length
1  NC_2424        3        1     30
2  NC_2424        5        1     30
3  NC_2424        6        1     30
4  NC_2424        7        1     30
5  NC_2424        8        4     30
6  NC_35131       14        4     34
7  NC_35131       15        6     34
8  NC_35131       16        2     34
9  NC_35131       20        3     34
10 NC_35131       21        1     34
```

. solution?

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(genome)
  tidyr::complete(genome, position =   seq(as.integer(unique(length))), length, fill = list(coverage = 0))
```

.

```
> df.out
    genome position coverage length
1  NC_2424        1        0     30
2  NC_2424        2        0     30
3  NC_2424        3        1     30
4  NC_2424        4        0     30
5  NC_2424        5        1     30
6  NC_2424        6        1     30
7  NC_2424        7        1     30
8  NC_2424        8        4     30
9  NC_2424        9        0     30
10 NC_2424       10        0     30
11 NC_2424       11        0     30
12 NC_2424       12        0     30
13 NC_2424       13        0     30
14 NC_2424       14        4     30
15 NC_2424       15        6     30
16 NC_2424       16        2     30
17 NC_2424       17        0     30
18 NC_2424       18        0     30
19 NC_2424       19        0     30
20 NC_2424       20        3     30
21 NC_2424       21        1     30
22 NC_2424       22        0     30
23 NC_2424       23        0     30
24 NC_2424       24        0     30
25 NC_2424       25        0     30
26 NC_2424       26        0     30
27 NC_2424       27        0     30
28 NC_2424       28        0     30
29 NC_2424       29        0     30
30 NC_2424       30        0     30
```

.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(genome = c("NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", 
"NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424"
), position = c(3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21), coverage = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 6, 2, 3, 1), length = c("30", "30", "30", "30", 
"30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

.

```
> dput(df.out)
structure(list(genome = c("NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", 
"NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", 
"NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", 
"NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", 
"NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", 
"NC_2424", "NC_2424"), position = 1:30, coverage = c(0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), length = c("30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", 
"30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", 
"30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", 
"30", "30")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyr::complete` you could do:

```r
tidyr::complete(df, genome, position = seq(30), fill = list(length = "30", coverage = 0))
#> # A tibble: 30 × 4
#>    genome  position coverage length
#>    <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> 
#>  1 NC_2424        1        0 30    
#>  2 NC_2424        2        0 30    
#>  3 NC_2424        3        1 30    
#>  4 NC_2424        4        0 30    
#>  5 NC_2424        5        1 30    
#>  6 NC_2424        6        1 30    
#>  7 NC_2424        7        1 30    
#>  8 NC_2424        8        4 30    
#>  9 NC_2424        9        0 30    
#> 10 NC_2424       10        0 30    
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

**Update**: You were on the right track using `group_by`. But you have to remove `genome` from the complete:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(genome) %>%
  complete(position = seq(as.integer(unique(length))), length, fill = list(coverage = 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

# Check to see if we have the desired number of obs per genome
count(df1, genome)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   genome       n
#>   <chr>    <int>
#> 1 NC_2424     30
#> 2 NC_35131    34
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(genome = c(
  "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424", "NC_2424",
  "NC_2424", "NC_35131", "NC_35131", "NC_35131", "NC_35131", "NC_35131"
), position = c(3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21), coverage = c(
  1,
  1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 6, 2, 3, 1
), length = c(
  "30", "30", "30", "30",
  "30", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -10L
))
```

Comment: If I want to loop this through several samples the length parameters will differ. Could you call this from the length-column instead if specifying directly?

Comment: Yeah. Sure. You could do `tidyr::complete(df, genome, position = seq(30), length, fill = list(coverage = 0))` to achieve the same result.

Comment: seq(30) still defines the length within the script?

Comment: Aw. Sorry. Did not realize that and misunderstood your question Just checked and you could do `tidyr::complete(df, genome, position = seq(as.integer(unique(length))), length, fill = list(coverage = 0))`

Comment: I have an updated question where I have multiple genomes in my input, I tried by grouping and then your script, but that did not work. Any solution how to perform this operation on multiple variables of genome? Please see updated question

Comment: Hi. You were on the right track. See my update.